# Connect via PHP to MySQL Database created using cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database and database user created via cpanel as below:

database name: test_database
database user: test_user

I am trying to connect to this database on the same server via a php script below:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "test_user_test_database";
$password = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

However I end up with:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'test_user_test_database'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/driver/public_html/login/connect.php on line 7
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'test_user_test_database'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Is the issue down to having an underscore in the username and database name? Or is there a way round this? I would much rather keep the username and database name as they are so wanted to check if there is any other way round it

Comment: according to what u write, ur db username is `test_user`, but in connection u use `test_user_test_database`

Comment: according to this http://forums.cpanel.net/f354/connecting-php-page-mysql-database-56011.html it needss to take the form username_databasename

Comment: It'd be better to use this resource as reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php not: http://forums.cpanel.net/f354/connecting-php-page-mysql-database-56011.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Underscores are fine for naming.

[`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) takes the database name as the 4th argument. Try adding your database name.

Finally, I seem to remember cPanel using some sort of automatic prefixes or something... double-check your database credentials if it's still not working.

You'll also have to add the user and the user permissions on that database.